# Yii2 Pjax GridView action buttons issue

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

I am trying to make an Ajax GridView using Pjax. Everything is working fine except the view, update and delete buttons are not AJAX. The code is:

```
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'demo']); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],

]); ?>
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

The problem is that the links for delete, view and update have the attribute data-pjax=0 which disables AJAX functionality. I cant find out how to set it too data-pjax=1.

Answer (score 7):

You must do like below:

**For Delete Action**

1- Change your delete action like below:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->isAjax) {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => ModelName::find(),
            'sort' => false
        ]);
        return $this->renderPartial('index', [
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ]);
    }
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

2- In your grid view:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'buttons' => [
            'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                            'data-pjax'=>'w0',
                ]);
            }
        ]
    ],
```

Now, it works with `Pjax`.

**Notes**

- My code in `deleteAction()` may decrease performance. You can write your own.
- `w0` usually is the default id of `PJax`. You can add an id to `PJax` and write it there instead.
- This is the same for `Update` and `View`, But you need to change the way you show your `update` and `view` views.
- This is highly recommended to take a look at `Yii2`'s official PJax document: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

Comment: In the delete action you are not deleting anything?

Comment: he does with $this->findModel($id)->delete();

Comment: hi, it is giving me an 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Comment: It gives you "405 Method not allowed" because a actionDelete need to be a POST request. So you need to add `'data-method' => 'post'` just after `'data-pjax'=>'w0'` in the gridview button options.
Look at [the framework documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter.html)

Comment: @user3658609 no sense to spend time helping this person - he is responsive when help is needed but leaves most of question without feedback. Lots of unsolved questions.