# Yii2 action with Pjax

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my yii2 application i've got this gridview with a custom action:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $data,
    'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'label' => 'Id Article',
                'value' => 'article.id',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Article Code',
                'value' => 'article.code',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Article Price',
                'value' => 'article.price',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Quantity',
                'value' => 'quantity',
            ],
            [
             'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
             'template' => '{delete}',
             'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key) {
                    if ($action === 'delete') {
                         return \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['estimate/delete-article', 'id_estimate_article' => $model->id]);
                    }
                }
            ], 

            ]
])  
?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

As you can see i'm wrapping my gridview with Pjax for handling Ajax responses.

This is the delete-article Action in my Controller:

```
public function actionDeleteArticle($id_estimate_article)
{
    $estimateArticle = EstimateArticle::findOne(['id' => $id_estimate_article]);    
    $id_estimate_head = $estimateArticle->estimate->id;
    $estimateAccessories = $estimateArticle->estimateAccessories;
    foreach ($estimateAccessories as $estimateAccessory) {
        $estimateAccessory->delete();
    }
    $estimateArticle->delete();
    return $this->redirect($this->redirect(\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['add-informations', 'id_estimate_head' => $id_estimate_head])));
}
```

The code works but the page refresh everytime (so Pjax isn't doing is job). This is my very first time that i use Pjax.

Where am i wrong?
Thanks in Advance for all the help

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491355/yii2-pjax-gridview-action-buttons-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your Pjax reload issue.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $data,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'label' => 'Id Article',
            'value' => 'article.id',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Article Code',
            'value' => 'article.code',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Article Price',
            'value' => 'article.price',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Quantity',
            'value' => 'quantity',
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'Action',
            'template' => '{delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a('Delete', yii\helpers\Url::to(['estimate/delete-article', 'id_estimate_article' => $model->id]), [
                        'class' => '',
                        'data' => [
                            'confirm' => 'Are you sure want to delete records?',
                            'method' => 'post',
                        ],
                    ]);
                }
            ]        
        ],

    ]
])
?>
```

I hope it will help you.